# Modals for speculations or logical deductions

Tags: modal-verbs, negation

Can you, please, help to choose the correct variant?

> The person on the right in the picture ***might not/can't/must not*** be who you say it is.

The answer key says that it is **must not**, but I have never come across negative form of must to be used for expressing possibility, certainty or probability. Is it possible to use it like that and why are *might not* and *can't* are incorrect?

Comment: *The answer key?* What's the ***question**?* All three versions are perfectly valid, but *by default* they all mean different things. Specifically, ***might not*** is probably warning the addressee that it's *possible* he misidentified someone. ***Can't*** implies the speaker believes you've made a mistake, where ***must not*** would normally be an extremely emphatic alternative to ***can't*** (in which context speaker might well have just presented a conclusive argument / incontrovertible evidence that it's *totally impossible* for your identification to be correct).

Comment: Along the lines of what @FumbleFingers said, please provide the preceding text or question (or state that there was none). It is impossible to determine what is intended without more context.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers! I feel relieved to see the confirmation that all the three variants are quite valid. There is no any preceeding or subsequent context to this sentence, just this one sentence and that's it, as it's taken out of a grammar test for upper-intermediate students